# Add more one button on Attach menu of Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

I've an idea to develop a modification to WhatsApp, for example now when I click attachment symbol it shows only 6 I want to add one more option to it. If it's possible let me know. I want to add more one button on Attach menu.

Comment: do you want to make changes to whatsApp or do you want to make other app like whatsapp with one more choice in attachment menu?

Comment: I want to make change to whatsApp. In this case, adds more one button on attach menu. So, i want to develop a app that when downloaded adds this button to whatsApp attachment menu.

Comment: No! you cannot add button to whatsapp. What you can do is add whatsapp to your app.

Comment: Ah.. but this app(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidsx.smileys) added a button to whatsApp. What i want to do is something like that, don't need to be on Attach menu.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but it will be specific solution for each platform, you have too many tags on your question for people to help you in my humble opinion.  For example on iOs you should look into UIDocumentInteractionController https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/ please edit your tags?

Comment: I'm sorry is the first time i ask in stackoverflow. I already edited. Any ideia where should i look for do this for android? And thanks for your answer

Comment: @Jef how can you make changes in whats app.He want to use his app url scheme in whatsapp. how?

Comment: @Avis ah thanks, I see only what is possible, to declare support for an exported file type/UTI. (exploiting a hook in the OS to appear in the 'push document to appX' menu..

Comment: @PedroMoura I recommend you ask one question each for iOs and Android and any other platform that interests you.  Be aware, as others have pointed out, that you will not be able to recompile the WhatsApp binary.  But there should be a 'hook' for an 'open In..' type menu. good luck and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: But it's pretty hard to hook your app to whatsapp without their permission, even to get approved by apple.!

Comment: Well everything is relative mate :)  Ive had a bunch of apps approved by Apple, as have many people here, you can do it.  I imagine the 6 other apps on that menu got there somehow right?  The question is, did the whatsApp people put those 6 there, or did it query the Os for 'apps that can handle file type X..' ?  Thats what Id be looking into if i was you

Comment: you are right @Jef i found documentation from whatsapp

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what exactly you are asking.

You have an option to launch other applications from your app.

If you want to change the way a certain app looks, or behaves you have to write something similar to it for people to use, but you cannot change the original app (no one will let you)

Comment: I want to add a button on the attach menu, isn't possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! it's possible, as @Jef said in comments.

using documentation interaction controller.

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013

you need to work on how to hook into attachment menu.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/

Comment: Ok, so in this link you gave me teaches how to adds a button in whatsapp?

Comment: Not exactly,But how to interact your app with whatsapp and documents exchange with whatsapp.

Answer (score 1):

There is an assumption in your question that these other apps are put there by the whatsApp developers, or by a third party who was somehow able to modify their code.  I suspect that what is happening is that they (whatsApp) simply export a document/file of a certain type (UTI)  If your application supports that same UTI it should appear here.  So there is six buttons for you, on your phone, but another user might see a different number, it depends entirely what they have installed on their device.

CONCEPTUAL.. if you double click on a file on your computer then the file browser (OS) opens that file with some application or other.  Perhaps it is a .doc file and the OS pushes that file to word or pages.  Or it may be a .psd file and it gets pushed to photoshop.  How does this happen?  The OS has a registry (database) of applications for each file type, applications sign up on this when they install/update.  If you right click on a file you see an 'open in..' option that lists all your applications which can handle that file type, this is the menu that you are wanting to get onto (for whatsApp's file type) imho.

So you need to 
1 ascertain what file type (UTI) WhatsApp is exporting

2 declare support for that file type in your application (this is the bit which will be platform specific solution)  (iOS docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1 )

**edit/addition
3. add the code to actually handle the file when your app receives it. On iOs this is in the appDelegate in

```
-(void) application: openURL: sourceApplication:annotation:
```

If the Whatsapp people have published an API then thats where you want to look. Good luck